# Can array of int pointers in C++ be done as ArrayList of Integer references in Java?

Tags: java, arraylist, int

I have an array `int[] A = new int[100000]` in Java and I want to create millions of subarrays of `A`. In C++ I would use arrays of pointers. Can I create `ArrayList<Integer> subA` and store references to elements of `A` such that I will not consume too much memory.
Right at the moment, I do create `int[] subA = new int[some value less than A.length]` objects which is very expensive and goes out of memory.

Comment: Not 100% sure, hence the comment, but Java does not allow pointer manipulation. Can't you have an Arraylist of smaller arrays?

Comment: Yes I can but will it be the same in memory to allocate `int[] subA = new int[100]` or `List<Integer> subA = new ArrayList<Integer>(100); for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) subA.add(A[i*100]);` ?

Answer (score 5):

`List.subList()` does that : it creates a view over the original list. You would probably save memory by using that, since a sublist has only these 4 fields:

- reference to the outer list
- offset
- size
- modCount

Each sublist would thus consume something like 20 bytes.

Comment: But sublist creates kind of a reference to the original List, right?

Comment: Yes, that's what I explained in my answer. Just like a pointer would in C++.

Comment: That's nice, but why I need to create a reference of a list if I can use my original list as reference itself?

Comment: Isn't it what you asked for? You want to create subarrays of an original array. replace array by list, and you thus want to create sublists of an original list. What's the problem? A reference is a pointer. It's the same thing, except you can't do arithmetics with references like you would with C++ pointers.

Comment: Let's make the questions simple, I have `int[] A new int[3] {1, 2, 3}`. How to make two subarrays `List<Integer> subA1 = {1, 3}, subA2 = {2, 3}` such that they will not store a copy of existing data (holding memory) but will store only references that will take little memory.

Comment: `List<Integer> a = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3); List<Integer> subA2 = a.subList(1, 3);`. subA1 is impossible to create, since it's not a sub array of your original array : it contains two non-adjacent parts of the original array. But you could imagine supporting that by creating your own structure with multiple offsets and sizes, and a single reference to the original list (or array).

Comment: Can I do this: `List<Integer> A = new ArrayList<Integer>(3); A.add(1); A.add(2); A.add(3); List<Integer> subA1 = new ArrayList<Integer>(2); subA1.add(A.get(0)); subA1.add(A.get(2)); List<Integer> subA2 = new ArrayList<Integer>(2); subA2.add(A.get(1)); subA2.add(A.get(2));`  Will these subarrays store references and not actual integer values?

Comment: This will store references to every Integer in the original array, but a reference to an Integer consumes as much memory as an int, so you won't get any benefit doing that. It will even be worse. What you need is a reference to the original array, and a set of regions, modeled as offset+size, just list subList() does.

Comment: int consumes 4 bytes, so from one side reference is like pointer, from another it consumes > 4 bytes. Very bad.

Comment: What do you think a C++ pointer consumes? It consumes the same as a Java reference. You would have the same memory problems in C++ than the ones you have in Java with this strategy. A reference is a pointer. They're the same thing.

Comment: So making an array list of pointers in C++ is worse than simply copying subarrays?

Comment: No it's not. For 32 bit systems: int* arr[8]; takes 8x4 bytes allocated - the same amount as if it was copied. So it's not better and not worth, it's just the same.

Comment: It's the same on 32 bits system, and it's worse on 64-bits system, just as in Java. And since you want 60 GB of data in memory, you must be on a 64-bits system.

Answer (score 0):

Java has no concept of pointers, therefore you cannot use a list of Integers to refer to other objects, but what you can do is this:

```
List<List<Integer>> l = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();

l.add(new ArrayList<Integer>()) // add a list which will hold integers as a reference in your main list.
```

If you're running out of memory, you need to allocate more heap memory to the JVM.  Read up on the -Xmx startup parameters you can pass to the JVM.

Comment: No, -Xmx does not help. I need 60Gb by creating `new int[]` each time that's why I'm looking for references or pointers if that is impossible.

Comment: What are you doing that requires 60Gb of data in memory?  Is there no way to divide and conquer this?

Comment: Actually I require much more than 60Gb, this is after divide and conquer has been done :)